# problem with free function again!!!(C linux)

Tags: c, linux, free

I have a problem with free() function in C linux. here is my sample code:

```
typedef struct
{
    char index[2];
    char color[2];
    char duration[2];
} ps;

ps *_ps = NULL;
```

I need to allocate and free the above structure repeatedly using the following function:

```
ps * readMatrix(mmc_item_item_screen *_item_screen,int rows,int skip)
{
    if(_ps)
    {
        free(_ps);
        _ps=(ps *)NULL;
    }

    _ps=(ps *)calloc(rows-1,sizeof(ps));


memset(_ps,'\0',((rows-1)*sizeof(ps)));
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        if((i+1)>=skip)
        {
            sprintf(_ps[i].index,"%d",i);
            sprintf(_ps[i].color,"%s",getCDKMatrixCell(_item_screen->matrix,i+2,1));
            sprintf(_ps[i].duration,"%s",getCDKMatrixCell(_item_screen->matrix,i+2,2));

        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(_ps[i].index,"%d",i);
            sprintf(_ps[i].color,"%s",getCDKMatrixCell(_item_screen->matrix,i+1,1));
            sprintf(_ps[i].duration,"%s",getCDKMatrixCell(_item_screen->matrix,i+1,2));

        }

    }

    return _ps;
}

main()
{
while(1)
....
_ps=readMatrix(_item_screen,rows,getCDKMatrixRow(_item_screen->matrix));
....
}
```

First time that I call the above function, _ps is NULL so free() is not invoked. but the second time(_ps already allocated), program crashes as soon as free() is called.

Can you help me with this?

(ps   and _ps are both global)

Thank you.
**Edit1** I put the whole function that manipulates _ps. and this is the only function working on _ps. could you help pllease?

Comment: The error is not in this code.

Comment: Note also that you don't need to cast your pointers which makes the code easier to read.

Comment: plain sigsegv or do you see some other error message like heap corruption?

Comment: You allocate `rows-1` elements but access `rows` elements in your loop

Comment: more comments by the author:1-code is single threaded 2-casting was removed as you suggested(thanks) 3-sigsegv! don't know what that is. will check if you kindly explain more plz 4-rows  and rows-1 are tackled by "skip" element in the for loop(any way, the program crashes before that!)

Comment: I don't know if it is an actual problem, but at least it is more than confusing that you have `_ps` global, return it from `readMatrix()` and assign it again to `_ps`. Either make it local to main and pass it to `readMatrix()` or keep it global and change `readMatrix` to return nothing.

Comment: @WAHID I don't see how any value for `skip` could avoid the overrun. You wrote the function works the first time, so the program crashes after writing to unallocated memory!

Comment: wahid:it doesn't crash "after" writing to memory, it crashes immediately upon calling free()

Comment: @WAHID If you write to unallocated memory, all kind of future misbehaviour can occur - including a crash at `free()`. Why don't you just fix it and test it?

Comment: Not concerning your problem, but `memset` is useless here has `calloc` already put zero in the allocated memory.  Also, you could look at the `realloc` function instead of `free`/`*alloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU ARE  allocating rows-1 elements but accessing rows elements in your loop..
so me because of that...
one more thing if your _ps is global then why you are returning that..???

Comment: right! I shouldn't return that.but can that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: its depend how you handle the return of that function..! yes it may cause problem

Comment: yep, that was the problem. this part of the code was the place i was sure I was right :) tanx bro!

Comment: Returning a global variable, or an argument of a function can be useful in some cases to shorten the code.  Some examples: `func(arg)->x;` instead of `func(arg); arg->x;`, `while(func()) {...;}`insead of `func();while(ps){...; func();}`, ...

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough code posted, but IMO, you said that ps and _ps are global, so once you free _ps there might be a chance it's being used somewhere else in your program, causing it to crash. 
I'd suggest you go over the program and see where _ps is used, or supply us with more code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A crash at `free()` means **probably** that either:

1. You already freed this memory,
2. The allocated memory was corrupted - check if you overridden some of the memory.
3. The pointer you try to free, is not the pointer returned from malloc / calloc - check if you changed `_ps` value somewhere.

Comment: somehow, you are right.  I hadnpt already  freed the memory, nor I had anything other than malloc/alloc/strdup......      I had CORRUPTED the memory. your answer was the first clue that raised my suspicion. other folks help me to spot it. tanx

Comment: @WAHID SABER - well I'm glad it's solved. had no time to look at it after answering...